# bash loop: for loop in older bash versions

Tags: bash

I have an older version of bash: 3.2.25
I am trying to write a for loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="K"

for k in {2..20..2}
do
  filename=$filename$k
done
```

This should give me:

```
K2
K4
.
.
K20
```

But this is what it gives me:

```
K{2..20..2}
K{2..20..2}
.
.
K{2..20..2}
```

Is it because it is an older version of bash? How can I get it to work? Listing all the values is not a solution because I'm going to have to use {5..201}.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That was added in bash 4, I believe.

You can do:

```
for (( k=5; k<=201; k+=2 )); do
    filename=$filename$k
done
```

Comment: For the record, the Bash arithmetic for loop was added in version 2.04.

Answer (score 3):

You could change the for loop to this syntax:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="K"
for ((k=2;k<=20;k+=2))
do
    echo "$filename$k"
done
```

Comment: It is worth noting that, for very large numbers, this is a better idea than either sequence expansion or `seq`, since it won't have to collect and hold all the numbers in memory before using them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `seq` program instead:

```
for k in $(seq 2 2 20); do
  filename=$filename$k
done
```

Comment: I am not a bash expert, but is there a reason to prefer seq over the built in for loop?

Comment: It is still the built-in for loop; it's just that `seq` is used instead of sequence expansion. The reason to use `seq` instead is, of course, because sequence expansion wasn't added until Bash 4 (and that it is compatible with other Bourne-like shells).

Comment: Other then for backwards comparability, the built in loop may actually be better to use as it wont spawn an external process.

Comment: s/sequence expansion/brace expansion/. Brace expansion was added in version 3; however, a 3rd argument to specify step size was not added until step 4.

Comment: @chepner: I don't have any old versions of bash lying around to verify it, but I'm rather sure that textual brace expansion (e.g. `/{s,}bin`) came long before the ability of brace expansion to produce numeric sequences.

Comment: You can check the [release notes](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS). Text sequences may have been supported even earlier, but numeric sequences were introduced in version 3, with arbitrary step sizes in version 4.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="K"

for k in $(seq 2 2 20)
do
  filename2=$filename$k
  echo $filename2
done
```

Test:

```
K2
K4
K6
K8
K10
K12
K14
K16
K18
K20
```